# Avoiding whitespace next to form UX vs SEO - how to compromise

Tags: seo, forms, ux

The problem:

On desktop view form inputs (with labels) take less that half of width of the website and we gets big whitespace next to form which is bad for websites SEO. In the other hand forms should be surrounded by whitespace because it helps user to go fast through them (nothing distracts him) and we (probably) gets better conversion rate.

So what would be the best compromise? If we add content next to form it will distract user, if we left this space blank Google punish us. Anyone have some good idea?

Of course we can provide very long inputs that takes full width of the website but it can be confusing for user and also can look a little bit odd.

[I post similar question in UX Stack Exchange to see SEO point of view.](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/87619/avoiding-whitespace-next-to-form-ux-vs-seo-how-to-compromise)

Comment: "big whitespace next to form which is bad for websites SEO" / "...Google punish us" - unless you can provide concrete references and clarify what you mean, these statements would appear to be false. Any whitespace that _benefits_ UX should not negatively affect SEO.

Answer (score 1):

I'll suggest making your UX top priority than your SEO, I don't understand why would you get penalized for white space around your form labels. Forms are not exactly the best place to focus on when you are working on your SEO. If you really want to, you can have some descriptive text about the page, above or below the form. This way, it would serve as a data point for search engines without confusing your users.

Also, I'm assuming that the whitespace you are talking about is the result of some crafty CSS. If you are achieving this via blank HTML tags or BR tags, I'd suggest to avoid them.

Comment: But what if our form is on important site in business context. For example adding opinion form on product page? We want make this url as good indexed as it is possible but also our form should be as usefull as it is possible.

Comment: That is very common example of forms. Your product page should already be having all the content a search engine would need. So, if your form doesn't contain a lot of blank HTML tags, then you shouldn't need to do anything for it.